# Cannot convert object to primitive value when iterating through request.connection

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have the following script to iterate through all the properties of the `request.connection` object:

```
p
 - for (var key in req.connection)
   | #{key} : #{req.connection[key]}
   br
```

On a Ubuntu server with Node.js v4.2.6 it prints out fine. On my Windows PC Node.js v6.9.2 I'm receiving the following error:

> Cannot convert object to primitive value

Thinking that one of the keys of the properties of `req.connection` is not a string, I have tried to protect with the following code:

```
p
 - for (var key in req.connection)
   if (typeof(key) === "string")
     | string #{key} : #{req.connection[key]}
     br
   else
     | Not string: #{typeof key}
     br
```

But the same error still persist in v6.9.2 at the fourth line. I am puzzled. What could be causing the error?

---

After feedback from the (first two) comments, I modified the code to:

```
p
 - for (var key in req.connection) 
   if (typeof(key) === "string" && typeof req.connection[key]!="object")
     | string #{key} : #{req.connection[key]}
     br
   else
     | Not string: #{typeof req.connection[key]}
     br
```

Only a type of `object` was causing the problem on the Windows v6.9.2 version. This is odd, as I have on the same page `#{req.connection}` and this came out as [object Object], even in Windows version.

Comment: please print the req.connection object. it seems like the value (not the key) of one of the keys is not a string.  if (typeof(key) === "string") &&   (typeof(req.connection[key]) === "string")

Comment: Well, you seem to imply that the problem is in the conversion of the keys to strings, but maybe the keys are fine, and the failure is in the conversion of the corresponding value to a string. In other words `#{reg.connection[key]}` seems to be the problem according to your explanation. There could be properties in Windows that don't exist in Linux that affect the results.

Comment: @Both, thanks. The offending item is when `req.connection[key]` is of type `object`.  This is odd, as elsewhere on the same page (in Windows) an object, eg `#{req.connection}`, is printed out as [object Object]. I am still puzzled.